# How to point blog to menu item in Mezzanine?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

How do you point blogs to a menu item in Mezzanine? I am able to point my blogs to Home using urls.py but how about to page types like link and richtextpage?

Comment: Have you seen http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-menus?

Comment: mezzanine docs does not mention how to such task.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rich text page, call it Blog or however you want, then in meta data group, in the field URL add `/blog/` or whichever is the url to the main blog app. Mezzanine will match the url with the page and will add the `Page` object to the rendering context, so you can use it in templates.